# How to use arrow functions inside other functions?

Tags: javascript, arrow-functions

[the full code is in the link](https://drive.google.com/open?id=1ZPqm5xZ95cnwsCeF6_QqhRWNlBomtNud) I am to trying declare an arrow function by assigning it to the variable `randomColor` using the `array.push()` method, but I am getting the error "randomColor is not defined" when I run the code. Please help.

```
function generateRandomColors(num){
 let arr = [];
 for(let i=0;i < num;i++){
     arr.push(randomColor());
 }
 return arr;
}

let randomColor = () => {
    //random for red
    let r = Math.floor(Math.random() * 256);
    //random for blue
    let g = Math.floor(Math.random() * 256);
    //random for green
    let b = Math.floor(Math.random() * 256);
    //return rgb
    return "rgb(" + r + ", " + g + ", " + b +")";
};
```

Comment: I'm not getting an error with the code you've given

Comment: Please post your *full* code, including the invocation of `generateRandomColors`, so that the problem can be reproduced

Comment: Hello , have shared the drive link for the full code ,but in the code have used var instead of let ,                                               
https://drive.google.com/open?id=1ZPqm5xZ95cnwsCeF6_QqhRWNlBomtNud

Answer (score 0):

When you use `let` (e.g. `let randomColor`), the variable you declare isn't usable before its declaration. So if you try calling `generateRandomColors` before your `let randomColor = ...` declaration, you'll find that `generateRandomColors` isn't yet defined.

See especially the [Temporal Dead Zone](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/let#Temporal_Dead_Zone) for `let` and `const`:

> Temporal Dead Zone
>
> `let` bindings are created at the top of the (block) scope containing the declaration, commonly referred to as "hoisting". Unlike variables declared with `var`, which will start with the value `undefined`, `let` variables are not initialized until their definition is evaluated. Accessing the variable before the initialization results in a `ReferenceError`. The variable is in a "temporal dead zone" from the start of the block until the initialization is processed.

If that doesn't solve your problem, can you share the code where you try calling `generateRandomColors`?